# How to pass value during button selection in collection view?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

Here I am having four collection views for my home screen in which for the one of the collection view I need to pass data from one view controller to another depending on buy now button action for a particular indexpath and for clicking on cell i had given different method by using segues can anyone help me how to get indexpath for the particular cell selected button ?

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "newCell",for:indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell
let arr = newCategoryImageArray[indexPath.row]
let itemlist = newModel[indexPath.row]
let urls = NSURL(string: arr)
cell.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(urls! as URL)
cell.nameLabel.text = itemlist.name
cell.priceLabel.text = String(describing: "$ \(itemlist.price).00")
cell.buyNowButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.buyNowButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(<#T##@objc method#>), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.7
return cell

func buyNowActionForNewCollection(button: UIButton){
let buttonPosition = button.convert(CGPoint(), to: newCollection)
let indexPath = newCollection.indexPathForItem(at: buttonPosition) 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func buyNowActionForNewCollection(button: UIButton){
 let buttonPosition = button.convert(CGPoint(), to: newCollection)
 let indexPath = newCollection.indexPathForItem(at: buttonPosition) 
 let yourVC = segue.destinationViewController as YourViewController;
 yourVC.passedArrayIndex = newCategoryImageArray[indexPath.row] // passedArrayIndex make the property in YourViewController
 }
```